# How to copy/move eclipse compiled code to other machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, junit

I have eclipse project for automated test scripts. The project has all the helper classes and test script. Currently I run a particular test script using Eclipse "Run As". But now I want to run it through jenkins. Jenkins is on another machine. So is there any way, to copy the eclipse compiled code (May be jar or war file) put it to jenkins machine.

Comment: is better if you use some csv, as git, then from jenkins you pull all code and build/test it

Comment: The way is: you put your source files under version control, you add a maven or gradle build file to your project (and you integrate that with Eclipse), then you let Jenkins build your project and run your tests whenever you commit/push to source control.

Comment: In short: there are many different ideas how to solve this. So your question is simply: too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any way, to copy the eclipse compiled code (May be jar or
>   war file)

In eclipse , Right Click on Project - > Export -> Web -> War

Or

The way how you could automatically let jenkins build.

1) Put or commit your files with build script in any convenient version control (e.g.  bitbucket).

2) Set the [configuration](https://www.coveros.com/version-control-your-jenkins-server-configuration-with-git/) for automatic build in jenkins.